# ExtJS 5.0.1 tagfield

Tags: forms, field, extjs5

Can anyone explain me, what am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to load data to store and select some of that on form load.

Here is what I came up with so far:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cjd

```
Ext.define('TagModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [{
        name: 'some_id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'some_value',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});

Ext.define('MyPanel',{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Some title',
    width: 200,
    heigh: 500,
    layout: 'anchor',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tagfield',
        anchor: '100%',
        displayField: 'some_value',
        valueField: 'some_id',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'TagModel',
            data: [{
                some_id: 0,
                some_value: 'value0'
            }, {
                some_id: 1,
                some_value: 'value1'
            }]
        }),
        // value: ['0']
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('MyPanel');
    }
});
```

It works well, but if you uncomment line 40, which should tell component to select items by their valueField config, it shows error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of undefined ext-all-debug.js:144157

According to the [specification](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag-method-setValue), value can be set as an array of strings associated to this field's configured valueField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted by the OP [Панов Владимир](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4218913/):

---

OK, I've found a solution:

The problem is in the source code of ExtJS. If anyone have same problem, you can use this override:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Tag, {
    findRecord: function(field, value) {
        var store = this.store,
            matches;

        if (store) {
            matches = store.queryBy(function(rec) {
                return rec.get(field) === value;
            });
        }

        return matches ? matches.getAt(0) : false;
    },
});
```